# Repeated user on SQL Server Cube

Tags: sql-server, cube, user-roles

I'd like to know why it is possible to have repeated users on a SQL Server role membership. More specifically in a cube.

The cube I'm talking about already existed when I started working here and it has the same user added to id twice. It even has the same SID.

```
    <Member>
      <Name>username</Name>
      <Sid>S-1-5-21-2977299124-1876462163-2290217735-164370</Sid>
    </Member>
    <Member>
      <Name>username</Name>
      <Sid>S-1-5-21-2977299124-1876462163-2290217735-164370</Sid>
    </Member>
```

I'm not actually having any problems with this, but as it just does not make sense I'd like to understand why it happens.

Thanks!